# How can I define python function for this input

Tags: python, function, arguments

i need to define a function named get function to get below inputs

```py
ls = get_func(['square', 'circle', 'rectangle', 'triangle'])

//if it was square get one input ,circle would get two input ,rectangle get get three input  

print(ls[0](1))
print(ls[1](2))
print(ls[2](2, 4))
print(ls[3](4, 5))
```

Comment: i am new to python ,it's not about not trying to find the answer ,it's because of i didn't find any article about this type of inputs anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could define a function that returns a list of functions:

```
def get_func(func_names):
    """Return a list of functions corresponding to a list of names."""

    def square(x):
        return x * x

    def circle(x, y):
        return x * y

    def rectangle(x, y):
        pass

    def triangle(x, y):
        pass

    func_by_name = {
        'square': square,
        'circle': circle,
        'rectangle': rectangle,
        'triangle': triangle,
    }

    return [func_by_name[name] for name in func_names]
```

A function that returns functions with different signatures is a good way to have fun bugs, but since there's no context on what you're trying to do I can't suggest a better way.

Comment: i'm not trying to only define a function , my whole problem is about handling these inputs 
i have access to input which is string and listed in ls but how can i access (x,y) after ls[n](x,y)

Comment: You can handle them any way that you like.  If you post a code snippet that actually does something and say what you want it to do instead, it might be easier to give you an answer that's useful.  :)

Comment: ```def get_func(inputs):
        if(inputs == "circle"):
            return x*y
        else if(inputs == "square")
            return x*x
ls = ['square', 'circle']

print(ls[1](1,2))
```
i need to access to x , y in my function body 
and call the function this way
ls[1](x,y) 
or 
ls[0](x)

Comment: Updated answer to be something a little closer to what I think you're looking for.